# How to make header full width

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

Hello i have been working on this theme called cleanco for a cleaning business, i want the header containing the logo, menu and other information to be full width. I inspected with dev tool and found this code,

#header-ext .container

{

```
   padding: 0 0px;
```

}

@media (min-width: 1200px)
constructed stylesheet
.container, .container-lg, .container-md, .container-sm, .container-xl, .woocommerce .content-area

{

```
max-width: 1140px;
```

}

I implemented it on the customize css section, the width increased but not as desired.

Here is a picture of the desired width of the header

[image]

Here is a picture of the result i got when i implemented the code

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

There are spaces by the side of the header thank you
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZBIoe.png

Answer (score 1):

you can add the css in .cleanco-navigation class

```
.cleanco-navigation   { position:absolute; left: 0; right: 0;}
```

here is the image of code: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ep1zs.png

Comment: Thanks alot it worked one more thing please can you help with the css to change menu hover colour. here is the link to the website: http://box5666.temp.domains/~thelebd4/nsocompany/peermont/

Comment: you can add following code with important .quadmenu-text:hover {  color: blue!important }